# Sum of binomial distribution with different probabilities of success

Tags: probability

Let $(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4)\sim Mult(n,4,p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4)$. What is the distribution of $X_1+X_2$?

So, we have $X_1\sim Bin(n,p_1),X_2\sim Bin(n,p_2)$. I guess the sum should also be  off the binomial distribution, but I don't know how to get the formal proof.
$$P(X_1+X_2=k)=\sum_{k_1}P(X_1=k_1 \text{ and } X_2=k-k_1)=\sum_{k_1}P(X_1=k_1)P(X_2=k-k_1),$$where the last step follows by independence. I'm stuck here. Any help?

Comment: Could you explain the meaning of the notation?  $(X_1,...,X_4)$ ~ Mult$(n,4,p_1,..p_4)$.

Comment: Use the distribution of $X_1$ and $X_2$. For example, $P(X_1=k_1)={n\choose k_1}p_1^{k_1}{(1-p_1)}^{n-k_1}$.

Comment: @herbsteinberg vector $X = (X_1, ..., X_4)$ follows a multinomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p$, where $p = (p_1, ..., p_4)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you take $n$ i.i.d. samples from the distribution $p$ on $\{1,2,3,4\}$ with probability mass function $p(i)=p_i$. $X_1$ is the number of samples equal to $1$, $X_2$ is the number equal to $2$.

You are correct, $X_i$ is distributed as $\operatorname{Bin}(n,p_i)$ (but the $X_i$'s are *not* independent).

Now, $X_1+X_2$ is the number of samples taking value *either* $1$ or $2$. If you think of it this way, it is immediate that each of the $n$ samples has probability $p_1+p_2$ to be in $\{1,2\}$, and that, since these $n$ samples are independent,
$$
X_1+X_2 \sim \operatorname{Bin}(n,p_1+p_2)\,.
$$